# how to set a button to mimic another button's backgroundresource

Tags: android, button

I want to know how I could change a buttons backgroundresource that mimics another button's background resource so that whenever I change that button's backgroundresource it another button mimics the looks of the first button...

for example:

```
 int icon = R.drawable.ic_icon; //more specifically I stored R.drawable.ic_icon in SQL and retrieve and save in int icon when retrieve from that table, so when the table is change the first button dynamically change on create;
 btn_01.setBackgroundResource(icon); //when this button is pressed it inflates a layout containing btn_02
 btn_02.setBackgrounResource(??????); //this button is on a different layout and is used by different activity and should take the backgroundresource of the button that have been pressed to call that layout.
```

I could use if else statement but I have different button to be copied by the second button and each button has different backgroundresource possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question fully but anyways here is what I got

You can put the resource id in the Intent before starting the activity when **Btn_01** is clicked.

```
Btn_01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("resource_key", R.drawable.ic_heart);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

then in your Activity2 you can just get your resource data and set to whatever button you want

```
int DEFAULT_RESOURCE = R.drawable.ic_close;
    int resourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("resource_key",DEFAULT_RESOURCE);
    Btn_02.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
```